# is a bad practice to control the children state with useImperativeHandle?

Tags: reactjs

I missed more information about this type of use in **React Docs**.

I've seen it in some codes and **it doesn't sound cool for me**.

I made an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-chaplygin-5bxwp

useImperativeHandle: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle

```js
const CheckItem = forwardRef(({ children, ...rest }, ref) => {
  const [checked, setCheck] = useState(false);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    toggle: () => {
      setCheck(checked => !checked);
    }
  }));

  return (
    <div
      {...rest}
      style={{ textDecoration: checked ? "line-through" : "none" }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely recommend against using refs for this. This situation can use the standard react approach: [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), and pass down props.

```
export default function App() {
  const [checked, setCheck] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Imperative Handles</h1>

      <CheckItem value={checked}>
        <h2>Item 1</h2>
      </CheckItem>
      <button onClick={() => setCheck(checked => !checked)}>
        Toggle item 1
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

// ....

const CheckItem = ({ checked, children, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <div
      {...rest}
      style={{ textDecoration: checked ? "line-through" : "none" }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the React document (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle), it stats that:

> useImperativeHandle customizes the instance value that is exposed to parent components when using ref. **As always, imperative code using refs should be avoided in most cases**. useImperativeHandle should be used with forwardRef.

In your case, you can expose the `checked` as property. There is no reason to use **useImperativeHandle**